# Error while updating Angular 8.3.29 to 9.1.15

Tags: angular

After updating the @angular/core to 9.1.13 I got some errors as shown below

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.js 314:201-209
"export 'Renderer' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.js 350:99-107
"export 'Renderer' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.js 549:213-221
"export 'Renderer' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.js 603:12-20
"export 'Renderer' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.js 661:99-107
"export 'Renderer' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-chips/node_modules/ng2-material-dropdown/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ng2-material-dropdown.js 328:12-20
"export 'Renderer' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 836:24-36     
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 829:12-24     
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 826:202-214   
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 748:18-27     
Can't import the named export 'Component' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 819:22-34     
Can't import the named export 'ContentChild' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 746:9280-9303 
Can't import the named export 'DefaultValueAccessor' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 759:58-71     
Can't import the named export 'ElementRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 739:153-166   
Can't import the named export 'ElementRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 106:33-45     
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 100:32-44     
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 96:32-44      
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 94:28-40      
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 102:26-38     
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 104:26-38     
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 98:32-44      
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 837:24-35     
Can't import the named export 'FormsModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 830:12-23     
Can't import the named export 'FormsModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 827:8-19      
Can't import the named export 'FormsModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 775:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 777:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 769:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 771:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 779:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 781:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 799:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 817:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 797:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 795:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 815:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 783:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 791:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 789:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 785:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 773:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 787:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 793:22-27     
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 742:21-38     
Can't import the named export 'NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 751:37-54     
Can't import the named export 'NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 746:9205-9215 
Can't import the named export 'NgClass' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 746:9533-9551 
Can't import the named export 'NgControlStatus' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is 
available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 746:9896-9906 
Can't import the named export 'NgForOf' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 746:9815-9822 
Can't import the named export 'NgIf' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available) 
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 746:9618-9628 
Can't import the named export 'NgModel' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 833:18-26     
Can't import the named export 'NgModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 746:10002-10021
Can't import the named export 'NgTemplateOutlet' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 803:22-28     
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 805:22-28     
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 807:22-28     
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 809:22-28     
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 811:22-28     
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 813:22-28     
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 801:22-28     
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 36:18-22      
Can't import the named export 'Pipe' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available) 
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 759:83-95     
Can't import the named export 'Renderer2' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 739:179-191   
Can't import the named export 'Renderer2' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 820:23-34     
Can't import the named export 'TemplateRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 746:75-86     
Can't import the named export 'TemplateRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 763:22-31     
Can't import the named export 'ViewChild' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 760:22-31     
Can't import the named export 'ViewChild' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 766:22-31     
Can't import the named export 'ViewChild' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 746:10169-10189
Can't import the named export 'ViewEncapsulation' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 755:38-55     
Can't import the named export 'ViewEncapsulation' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 486:32-44     
Can't import the named export 'debounceTime' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 503:60-72     
Can't import the named export 'debounceTime' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 490:32-38     
Can't import the named export 'filter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 495:30-36     
Can't import the named export 'filter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 503:30-36     
Can't import the named export 'filter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 511:32-38     
Can't import the named export 'filter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 507:32-38     
Can't import the named export 'filter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 499:32-38     
Can't import the named export 'filter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 483:18-24     
Can't import the named export 'filter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 743:25-35     
Can't import the named export 'forwardRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 752:41-51     
Can't import the named export 'forwardRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 473:27-36     
Can't import the named export 'fromEvent' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 474:29-38     
Can't import the named export 'fromEvent' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 473:83-86     
Can't import the named export 'map' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)  
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 474:87-90     
Can't import the named export 'map' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)  
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 33:139-157    
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is 
available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 739:204-222   
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is 
available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 825:155-173   
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is 
available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 35:0-27       
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 747:0-27      
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 832:0-27      
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 740:29-52     
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareComponent' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 33:21-42      
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export 
is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 739:29-50     
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export 
is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 825:29-50     
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export 
is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 828:29-51     
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjector' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 826:29-51     
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs 34:22-40      
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclarePipe' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is 
available)
```

I have tried updating the node_modules that it has mentioned in the errors **angular-ng-autocomplete** and **ngx-chips** but this didn't solve any of them. I will provide you all my dependencies and dev-dependencies below

Can some one help me out.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^6.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^6.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.3",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^1.1.1",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^6.1.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^11.2.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^15.0.2",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.48",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.47",
    "@types/d3-shape": "^1.3.12",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.29",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.36",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.25.2",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.12",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "bourbon": "^4.3.4",
    "chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "crypto-js": "^3.3.0",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.13.11",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^5.1.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng-chartist": "^1.1.1",
    "ng-click-outside": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2": "^0.2.4",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.9.0",
    "ng2-material-dropdown": "^1.0.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.3",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.7.2",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ng6-toastr-notifications": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.9.8",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^4.8.0",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^1.4.9",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nouislider": "^11.1.0",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "primeng": "^6.1.3",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "screenfull": "^3.3.1",
    "socket.io-client": "2.2.0",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.2",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.12.9",
    "videogular2": "^6.0.6",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
```

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.15",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.16",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.43",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.23",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/node": "^9.6.55",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your @angular/cli (and core) and @angular/material don't match.

Try running `ng update @angular/material` to bump material to v9.

---

*Note*:

Given the number of dependencies, you might want to check compatibility for each of the libraries you use.